# Issue with data field selection using Docusign

Tags: docusignapi

i am working on pdf in docusign, facing an issue while making selection between two data fields. Data fields have been marked as required, i have to make sure that if one enters some text in one field than other field should get disabled automatically and vice versa..
For example:
There are two data fields A and B and both are marked as required
If one enters some data in A then B should get disabled or B will no more be mandatory field and vice versa.
Can anybody suggest solutions for the same?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you tried using DocuSign Conditional Fields?

Comment: Yes i have tried. Still not getting solution. It is working fine in one direction but not allowing to do reverse.

Comment: I still think you should be able to get this working using Conditional Fields.  What if you made two grouped radio buttons (Option A and Option B).  If the user selects Option A then make one of the data fields accessible, if they select Option B then make the other field accessible